# How to decompose a type constructor via implicits?

Tags: scala, implicit, scalaz, shapeless, higher-kinded-types

I have a class `Foo` that takes a type constructor `F` as type parameter:

```
case class Foo[F[_]](x: F[String])
```

Now I want to define a member method `bar` that is only applicable, if `F[T] = Outer[Inner[T]]` for some fixed outer type `Outer`, e.g. `Option`:

```
def bar[Inner[_]](implicit ev: ???): Foo[Inner]
```

The `???` must be something along a natural transformation `F ~> Outer·Inner` with `·` being composition of type constructors.

1. How does this implicit argument look like?
2. How can I get it from somewhere?

### How to write type constructor composition?

Also how to best write composition of type constructors? I currently write using a type lambda `({type L[X] = Outer[Inner[X]]})#L`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Type equality for type constructors

I don't think there's one defined in ScalaZ, but it's fairly simple to make one, taking `scalaz.Leibniz` as a template. I won't focus on composition and convenience methods, and only get the substance:

```
sealed abstract class LeibnizK[F[_], G[_]] {
  def subst[Z[_[_]]](p: Z[F]): Z[G]
}

object LeibnizK {
  implicit def refl[F[_]] = new LeibnizK[F, F] {
    override def subst[Z[_[_]]](p: Z[F]): Z[F] = p
  }
}
```

Which seems to be the implicit you're looking for:

```
type Outer[A] = Option[A]
type Id[A] = A

case class Foo[F[_]](me: F[String]) {
  // Oh boy, here comes type lambda
  def bar[Inner[_]](implicit leibk: LeibnizK[
    F,
    ({type L[A] = Outer[Inner[A]]})#L
  ]): Outer[Foo[Inner]] = leibk.subst(this).me.map(Foo(_)) // <- OK to use methods of Outer
}

assert(Foo[Option](Some("meh")).bar[Id] == Some(Foo[Id]("meh")))
```

- *[ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/8eXBNz4/0)*

## Better syntax for type composition

Check out [kind projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) compiler plugin. It allows you to write:

```
λ[A => Outer[Inner[A]]
// or
Lambda[A => Outer[Inner[A]]
```

instead of

```
({type L[A] = Outer[Inner[A]]})#L
```

And for simple cases (no nesting), there's even shorter syntax

```
(?, Int)
```

instead of

```
({type L[A] = (A, Int)})#L
```

Comment: Thanks. I did the [same with `~>`](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/a3sRgDg/0). It appears to be simpler.